# NSURLCache - does it work on OSX with on-disk caching?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsurlconnection, nsurlcache

I can't get success with `NSURLCache` on OSX (10.7):

```
NSURLCache *cache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:1024*1024*20
                                                  diskCapacity:1024*1024*5
                                                      diskPath:NSHomeDirectory()];

[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:cache];

NSMutableURLRequest *req=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://wikipedia.org/"]
                                                 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad 
                                             timeoutInterval:60];

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSLog(@"Received %lu bytes", [data length]);

sleep(10);

[req setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad];
data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSLog(@"Received %lu bytes", [data length]);
```

1. The first problem is if I build this with SDK10.6 second request receives 0 bytes..
2. If I build it with SDK10.7 it seems working, but I can't use the cache for persistent storage - after I restart the program the first response is not loaded from cache it is loaded from server. If I initialize request with `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad` cache policy I'll get 0 bytes in response.
3. If I set memory limit to for example 5 bytes, second request receives 0 bytes.

The file Cache.db is created in both cases and seems has a valid data, but on-disk caching doesn't work.

Whats wrong with `NSURLCache`? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any particular reason you're creating your own cache? The default one usually suffices

Comment: @MikeAbdullah there is no reason. Default cache also doesn't work

Comment: This code worked in 10.8 for me.

Comment: There's pretty clearly something wrong with NSURLCache. I've been looking into the issue from the iOS side, but it seems some of the issues are the same on the Mac. In my tests on iOS, the cache seems to only work properly when the memory capacity is equal to the disk capacity. Otherwise, it returns responses when the data happens to be in memory and returns nil if the data is only cached on disk. I have a bug report into Apple, and I'd suggest that you file one against OS X as well. Let us know what you find.